# MacBook Pro Keyboard - How to Swap / Remap Keys?

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, keyboard, macbook, remapping

I know this may be asked before in a different manner, but I still haven't really seen a solid answer. I'm hoping that providing these 2 specific needs will make it more clear.

I specifically want 2 behaviors that will make my transition from a long time PC user to being able to use a MacBook Pro.

Background:

- I am a windows user that just got my first mac ever (in my life) this past weekend.
- I am dual booting the MBP with Snow Leopard and Windows 7 x64

What I want to do (in both Windows 7 and Snow Leopard):

- Swap the <kbd>fn</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd> keys (not physically)
- Be able to tap the <kbd>eject</kbd> key for a forward delete, but keep the ability of holding down the <kbd>eject</kbd> key to actually eject the disc.

Are these possible, if so what is the best way (software?) of accomplishing this in both Windows 7 and Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 14):

On OS X: [**DoubleCommand**](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/)

[image]

On Windows: [**SharpKeys**](http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/)

[image]

For anything more extensive, you'll want [**AutoHotkey**](http://autohotkey.com) (Windows) or [**IronAHK**](http://code.google.com/p/ironahk/) (AutoHotkey rewrite that works with Mono for cross-platform compatibility - Linux, Mac, etc).

Comment: sharp keys isn't allowing me to remap the [fn] (function) key

Comment: and DoubleCommand only allows me to map fn -> control but not control -> fn

Comment: Take a look at the alternatives, they are much more flexible.

Comment: Any update on this in 2021? It seems Big Sur doesn't allow this anymore and I'm in the same situation as OP (first-time Mac user hoping to map keys to Windows type keyboard)

Answer (score 8):

On the Snow Leopard side you can swap Control and Fn with [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en) (formely KeyRemap4MacBook).

If you're dual-booting, a good idea is to swap Command and Control in OS X's preferences. You'll get physically same keyboard shortcuts on both.

Comment: It's now called Karabiner.

Answer (score 3):

Just as a sidenote you may also consider taking a look at the normal OS X system preferences under Keyboard there is a button on the lower-right named "Modifier keys" where you can define which actions should be taken by the modifier keys (caps-lock, ctrl, cmd,...). Could also be enough in some situation without installing 3rd-party software.

Answer (score 1):

There is [keyboard maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) that does this

Answer (score 1):

As John T pointed out, [AutoHotKey](http://autohotkey.com) does everything on Windows, and that's it.

For Mac, [IronAHK](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/102633-ironahk-still-a-thing) used to be good too, back when it existed.

So there's another option that, while I could never really use, seems to do what you need. Although it's very very technical, it's highly customizable. I'll just quote the website:

> [**Ukelele**](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele) is a *Unicode
>   Keyboard Layout Editor* for Mac OS X
>
> Ukelele aims to simplify keyboard
>   layout editing by providing a
>   graphical interface to .keylayout
>   files, where the desired characters
>   can simply be dragged onto keys as
>   needed. (The **Character Palette**,
>   available in the Input menu if it has
>   been enabled in **System Preferences**, is
>   a great place to find the characters.)
>
> In addition to simple assignment of
>   single character codes to keys,
>   Ukelele can assign multiple-character
>   strings and can create "dead keys",
>   where a keystroke sets a new state
>   that modifies the output of the
>   following keystroke.

Hope it can help you where it couldn't for me back when I found it. ;)

Comment: autohotkey does not detect Fn key. You could use it to remap Caps Lock however.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/), it's a free tool with wich you can reprogram keys and multi-touch gestures. Make sure that in your settings you have set the F1, F2, etc-keys as default. Open BetterTouch and remap your keyboard. Don't forget to automatically let it run after logging in. It's also a very usefull tool for working with multi-touch gestures. I use it to swipe through my Spaces with four fingers. I don't like the default gestures in Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, someone implemented a kernel-mode driver to do this magical feat for the wireless Apple keyboard. I am not sure if it works for a macbook. The FAQ says that an option is to install Windows "natively." Regardless, there is a good chance a small modification to the source code could get it working everywhere.

https://github.com/samartzidis/WinA1314