# Is there a way to remap the Fn and Ctrl keys on an Apple wireless keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, wireless-keyboard

I'm using Apple Wireless keyboard and I'm slightly disappointed that <kbd>Fn</kbd> key and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key have that order. It's not convenient for me. How can I easily swap them?

Comment: which OS?
Mac or Windows?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Windows:

It can be done using [SharpKeys 2.1.1](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/):

> SharpKeys is a utility that manages a Registry key that allows Windows to remap one key to any other key. Included in the application is a list of common keyboard keys and a Type Key feature to automatically recognize most keyboard keys.

- **What you can do:**

  > Map an entire key to any other key - e.g. you could remap Caps Lock to a Shift key
- **What you can't do:**

  > Allow you to swap two keys with each other - e.g. you can’t have Q and Z swap places because the remapping code would get confused

---

### Mac OS X

It can be done using [DoubleCommand](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/):

> DoubleCommand is software for Mac OS X (a kernel extension) that lets you remap keys, in other words change the way your keyboard works. Often used to make a PC keyboard more comfortable with a Mac, swapping the Alt (Option) and Windows (Command or Apple) keys, since they are in swapped positions on Mac and PC keyboards. DoubleCommand is a quick and easy way to fix this if you use a PC keyboard with your Mac.

---

#### Related reading:

I've found the [MacBook Pro Keyboard - How to Swap / Remap Keys?](https://superuser.com/q/45849/94664) to contain useful information on this subject.

Comment: Thanks for the `DoubleCommand` software link, I've found it before see your post :) But it helps me.
And I have another problem: how to redefine `eject`? Is it possible?! I want to set it `delete` behavior... Fu**ing apple devs think that we don't use `delete` or it's convenient to type `fn+backspace` instead of `delete` when programming?

Comment: Also with `DoubleCommand` I have a problem when use combo shortcuts (for example, `Ctrl+Shift+Up`. Only original buttons work...

Comment: DoubleCommand cannot swap them, according to the info on the web site.  It can only remap the `fn` key into a `control` key.

Comment: Sharpkeys can't detect the fn key on an Apple keyboard. http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/faq.htm #15

Comment: On windows. You can remap fn to ctrl with program https://magicutilities.net/. It requires pay early, but It has 30 day trial.
Or free programm only for apple keyboard 2015 https://github.com/samartzidis/WinAppleKey

Answer (score 6):

Alas, this most probably won't work.
With the exception of exchanging the bluetooth keyboard's firmware or rewire the harddware buttons.

**Reason**:
The Fn key is a modifier for the generated scancodes. This key is a modifier at the hardware level. A fn keypress cannot be seen even (using 'xev' on my Apple bluetooth keyboard under linux)

EDIT: A quick test shows it might be possible (using showkey on a real tty):
Fn has keycode 464
Ctrl has keycode 29

Answer (score 4):

For versions up to (and including) 10.11, you can swap the keys with [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en) (formerly KeyRemap4MacBook), while DoubleCommand can only turn your <kbd>fn</kbd> key into a <kbd>control</kbd> key.

For versions 10.12+, you'll want to use [Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements), a complete rewrite of Karabiner, that is still catching up to the function available in Karabiner.  The features that it supports are still in flux.

Comment: Fantastic, this works on OSX 10.11.x.

Comment: For macOS Sierra you'll want to get [Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 4):

Under Windows, installation of the following driver allows to easily swap Ctrl and Fn.

https://github.com/samartzidis/WinAppleKey

In addition to that, cmd/win and alt can be swapped too and some Fn+Key combinations from the Mac layout are installed:

- Ctrl -> Fn (configurable at installation)
- Fn   -> Ctrl (configurable at installation)
- Left/Right Alt   -> Left/Right Windows (configurable at installation)
- Left/Right Windows   -> Left/Right Alt (configurable at installation)
- Eject    -> Delete
- Fn + Backspace   -> Delete
- Fn + Enter   -> Insert
- Fn + F3  -> (App) My Computer
- Fn + F4  -> (App) Calculator
- Fn + F5  -> Pause/Break
- Fn + F6  -> Print Screen
- Fn + F7  -> previous track
- Fn + F8  -> play/pause
- Fn + F9  -> next track
- Fn + F10 -> mute
- Fn + F11 -> volume down
- Fn + F12 -> volume up
- Fn + Up  -> Page Up
- Fn + Down    -> Page Down
- Fn + Left    -> Home
- Fn + Right   -> End

Comment: The link is bad :(

Comment: The project was renamed apparently. I updated the link in the answer. Also, the project's description says that Win 10 is supported, and Win 7 and other versions might work, but were not tested. I just tested on 64 bit Win 7 and the installation blue-screened my computer.

Comment: Anyone knows of a similar tool for the laptop keyboard itself? macbook pro retina 13 mid 2014

Answer (score 2):

When you are using Linux I think it should be possible, too. At least when you have access to your system and you can recompile your kernel. Check this out [Linux: Apple Wireless A1314 Fn key not registered, looks like software bug](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41537/linux-apple-wireless-a1314-fn-key-not-registered-looks-like-software-bug).

Answer (score 2):

*(Addition to Zuuls answer)*

### Linux

I have tried modifying the kernel module for Apple Keyboards [here](https://github.com/JanmanX/HID-Apple) . If you have Linux kernel version 3.13 (or close), it should be easy to load it.

I have no experience writing kernel modules, so some of the code may not work as expected. As far as I know, it works on my keyboard :)

Comment: Is there a more up to date solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have built a little open source project for this: [Bluetooth HID Hub](https://github.com/ruundii/bthidhub). It runs on Raspberry Pi Zero W (~$10/£10).

It is similar to RaspiKey, but:

- Supports not only a keyboard, but a mouse as well, both wired or wireless
- Does not require wire connection to your computer
- Supports connection to multiple computers (work on 2+ machines with the same keyboard
- Python based, so really easy to extend with your custom remappings or any other device specific logic

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tool that can help you  [sharpkeys](https://www.randyrants.com/category/sharpkeys/)
for fn and control, and for other short cuts you can use power toys.
here is a video on how to do it : [youtube: fn remap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdaiihdCs-s)